# Custom alertViewController in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I would like to show a popup (I just have `UIAlertController` in mind) like the the image below:

> What I want to achieve

[image]

I found some kind of similar questions on the internet but they are code based, this way it is really hard to align the stuff in the position I want and handle the user interaction.

Is there a way that I kinda make a separate "Something" in the `Storyboard` and then here just pop that up? I thought of a whole `ViewController` but that covers the whole screen.

Any suggestions or solutions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to present it modally , so make the VC give it identifier and load it anywhere

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popupID") as! PopupViewController

vc.sendedStr = "someContent"

vc.myImage = UIImage(named:"flag.png")     

vc.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true;

vc.definesPresentationContext = true;

vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

self.present(vc, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

//

```
class PopupViewController : UIViewController {

    var sendedStr:String?

    var myImage:UIImage?      
}
```

More importantly is to set background of the view in IB like this 
[image]

Comment: Thank you, how do I send some information to the `PopupViewController` then? like some string, an `UIImage` and so on? I knew to use `segue` but here there is no `segue`.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewController` Doesn't fill the entire screen all the time. This is just the default setting.

Set `.modalPresentationStyle` property of your child controller to `.overCurrentContext` and present it modally.

Now, if you view Controller has an transparent background, it will be presented like an alert.

Answer (score 1):

First design viewController in storyBoard and keep in mind your ViewController main view background color should be either clear or change its Alpha to like 0.5

Add below extension

```
extension UIViewController {
    open func presentPOPUP(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, modalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical, completion: (() -> Swift.Void)? = nil) {

        viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        viewControllerToPresent.modalTransitionStyle = modalTransitionStyle

        self.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)

    }
}
```

After that you can use it like below

```
if let alerVC = self.myStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AlertMessageVC") as? AlertMessageVC {
       self.presentPOPUP(alerVC, animated: true, modalTransitionStyle: .crossDissolve, completion: nil)
}
```

you can also change modalTransitionStyle to below options

```
 .coverVertical
 .flipHorizontal
 .crossDissolve
 .partialCurl
```

Hope this help. :)